# Copying several columns from a csv file to an existing xls file using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv

I'm pretty new to Python but I was having some difficulty on getting started on this. I am using Python 3.

I've googled and found quite a few python modules that help with this but was hoping for a more defined answer here. So basically, I need to read from a csv file certain columns i.e G, H, I, K, and M. The ones I need aren't consecutive.

I need to read those columns from the csv file and transfer them to empty columns in an existing xls with data already in it.

I looked in to openpyxl but it doesn't seem to work with csv/xls files, only xlsx.
Can I use xlwt module to do this?

Any guidance on which module may work best for my usecase would be greatly appreciated. Meanwhile, i'm going to tinker around with xlwt/xlrd.

Comment: xlwt/xlrd I used.  They seem to work fine for me.  Python has a csvreader

Comment: I forgot to mention. Each of these columns in the csv file has about 9k entries...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using pandas. It has convenient functions to read and write csv and xls files.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#read the csv file
df_1 = pd.read_csv('c:/test/test.csv')

#lets say df_1 has columns colA and colB
print(df_1)

#read the xls(x) file
df_2=pd.read_excel('c:/test/test.xlsx')
#lets say df_2 has columns aa and bb

#now add a column from df_1 to df_2
df_2['colA']=df_1['colA']

#save the combined output
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('c:/test/combined.xlsx')
df_2.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()

#alternatively, if you want to add just one column to an existing xlsx file:

#i.e. get colA from df_1 into a new dataframe
df_3=pd.DataFrame(df_1['colA'])


#create writer using openpyxl engine
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('c:/test/combined.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 

#need this workaround to provide a list of work sheets in the file
book = load_workbook('c:/test/combined.xlsx')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

column_to_write=16 #this would go to column Q (zero based index)
writeRowIndex=0 #don't plot row index
sheetName='Sheet1' #which sheet to write on

#now write the single column df_3 to the file
df_3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetName, columns =['colA'],startcol=column_to_write,index=writeRowIndex)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Wow! I'll definitely give this a try! So there are ways in the panda module to pick specific columns in the csv file and store in specific columns in the xls file? Edit: also these files have a large amount of data in them, like 10k entries for each column.

Comment: I would recommend reading both the csv and the xls files, combine the columns that you want and save everything to a new file. Is that a possibility?

Comment: Yeah I that would work as well. Will have to look in to how to combine the columns. Will the amount of entries cause an issue?

Comment: I understand everything but df_2.to_excel(writer, 'Scores 1'). What is this meant to do?

Comment: that line saves the content of df_2 (which is now extended with the new column) to the writer object that links to your output xlsx file. I deleted 'Scores 1', that was a leftover from another example. that string specifies which sheet to save in. pls accept answer if it was helpful

Comment: Do the column names have to be defined in the xlsx sheet before hand to add from csv? for the step df_2['colA']=df_1['colA']

Comment: no, in this example, the column with name colA did not exist in the xlsx file and therefore not in df_2 either before we added it.

Comment: It seemed I had to add the column names in the example csv and xlsx i used, for it to work. Thanks for the help! I'll try to figure out why this is happening. I used a csv file with no column names, and a xlsx file with no column names.

Comment: by default, the first row is used as header. check out the ref: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Keep getting an Keyerror no matter what I use for df_1. I have a column named LOCATION in df_1 that i need to paste to an empty column Q in df_2

Comment: df_2['LOCATION ']=df_1['LOCATION ']?

Comment: if you really want to specify the columns to use for writing, you can provide the 'column' parameter to to_excel. see documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: yeah thats what i'm using but still getting KeyError. so to use the column parameter in to_excel, do I just put the default column name? like df_2.to_excel(writer, Q)

Comment: no, column specifies which 'column' from the dataframe to use. you can select which xlsx column to write to via startcol. see expanded example

Comment: Okay so i managed to get it working. the issue was so very dumb. there was a space in the column names for df1... Any idea why when we get the new xlsx file is there a new column at A with numbers? I'm going to try to add the rest of the columns i need to see if it works. Thanks for all the help @jlarsch !

Answer (score 1):

You could try XlsxWriter , which is fully featured python module for writing Excel 2007+ XLSX file format.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter